# Windows 8 . Headphones detected but no sound

Tags: windows-8, headphones

I have a big problem with sound on my computer. I have Realtek High definition Audio sound and it is not working ok. Here is the situation:
On device manager I can see (under Audio inputs and outputs)

- Realtek Digital Input,
- Realtek Digital output (2x),
- Microphone (Realtek High definition Audio) and
- Realtek HD Audio 2nd output (heaphones icon).

In Realtek HD Audio Manager I have HD Audio 2nd output as default output for front green jack. Everything looks fine - no conflict or anything like that.

When I start my computer in headphones I can hear that silent constant sound, like you hear when you turn on speakers. So everyhing looks ok.

When I play some thing (youtube for example) I can see (on right bottom corner) that Realtek HD Audio 2nd output (headphones) is actually playing the sound. So everything ok again.

But no sound is coming from headphones. It is driving me crazy - I tried every combination of checkboxes and radio buttons in Realtek HD Audio Manager.

I really don't know what to do any more. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I met similar issue. Cold-booting solved it, though imperfect.

Comment: some realtek audio managers have a preferance option that changes the exclusivity of the front for the rear. This one says "mute the rear when the front is plugged in" & "make the front and rear 2 seperate playback devices" Did you try that button (or is it even there)?  Once it is a seperate playback device, I assume you have to arrange to use it, in whatever software (some can change output devices) or the system default.

Comment: It looks like motherboard doesn't have enabled back side jack's. In Realtek HD Audio Manager they are always disabled. And I cannot find where could I change that....

Comment: Please supply the number of the realtek chip that is being used here in the question (you can find it in the specs for the motherboard) .  Supply the version of the driver and software as best as possible, and the manufacture of the computer/motherboard.  It may help to find more info, but no promises.

Comment: PC wizzards shows Gigabyte H57m-USB3 motherboard with Device Audio : GigaByte Technology 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio and - this is strange - another audio device: Device Audio : ASUSTeK Computer GT200 High Definition Audio Controller. 
So it looks like I have 2 audio devices, but system doesn't show me any conflict!?!
In win8 device management there are 2 High definition Audio Controller - one on bus 0 and one on bus 1. It looks like there is none Realtek audio thing here....

Comment: It sounds like you may not have the driver stuff installed, sometimes the driver would rename these generic HD audio items to thier knowns.  http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3443#dl the place to get the drivers, and NOTE that the board like some gigabyte boards come in 2 "revisions" it is easy to miss that button on support for which board revision. All these MB makers will eventually abandon important support, so it "can be" that a better software exists for the chip on the board , but it is best to use what they provide. the chip is the "Realtek ALC889 codec"

Answer (score 2):

I will add this as an answer because I arrived at this thread looking for one and found none. I had reinstalled/updated my audio drivers, performed windows update, etc. etc., and none worked.

I then did this ([source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/no-sound-when-i-plug-in-headphones-after-windows-8/006f1aeb-46e6-454d-9f05-a8c49c2819a9)):

```
I had the same problem, I solved it by disabling the Fast Startup functionality in Control Panel:
1. Go to Control Panel->Power Options->Choose what the power buttons do
2. Uncheck Turn on fast startup
3. Perform full shutdown by calling the shutdown /s /t 0 in console or create shortcut with this command and run it
4. Turn on the computer, now the headphones should work ok :)
```

To be completely honest, I dont see what would solve this problem in this solution. Maybe it was just the reboot? (also, I had Fast Startup already uncheked before).

Either way, I thought about giving this tip, it may help others in the future.

Comment: Don't know how, but it worked for me... i reinstalled audio drivers, updated, nothing happened. Did this fast startup with a cold boot and it worked...

Comment: I'm having a similar problem under Windows 7 too. Full shutdown seems to solve the issue. Don't know why.