# Headphone doesn't work with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, headphones

I'm a bit confused, because it was working, I restarted the system and "puft!", doesn't work anymore. It works fine under Linux though.

The speakers do work and the Realtek audio manager detects that the headphone is plugged in (3.5mm jack), but no sound.

I already tried to reinstall the Realtek drivers, use the Windows' default ones, but nothing worked.

My adapter is `Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio`.

Answer (score 1):

## First Try Using Sound Troubleshooter

It usually fixes the most common problems very fast. If that cannot fix the problem. Follow the steps below.

## Steps

First unplug your headphone. Right click your speaker icon in the notifications area and select playback devices. Check to see your speaker/headphone is set as the default playback device.If it or If not set your speaker as the default playback device and the default communications device.Then plug your headphone and reopen the playback devices window again to see if the headphone device shows up.

### If It Shows Up

Then set that as the default playback if it shows up.
Check your headphones now. It should be working.

#### No Sound

If still no sound, double click the headphone which you just made the default playback device. A dialog box should open. Go to the levels tab and check the volume or mute. If that is fixed and it still doesn't work go to advanced tab and click on the test button. You should hear two 3 sequence tones through you headphones.

### If It Does Not Show Up

If it does not show up just double-click your default playback device.Go to the levels tab and check the volume or mute. If that is fixed and it still doesn't work go to advanced tab and click on the test button. You should hear two 3 sequence tones through you headphones.

## Still No Sound ?

### Further Steps

If you still do not hear any sound through your headphones then it might be something wrong with your drivers.

Go to device manager by right clicking your start menu. Then go to Audio Inputs And Outputs. From there you should see a list very similar to your playback devices in your sound control. Right click your device ( in my case 'speakers') and click on 'Update Driver Software' followed by 'Search automatically for updated driver software'. If a new update is found install It. Then do the above steps again.

If it does not work for Audio Inputs And Outputs, try doing the same for your soundcard driver from 'Sound,video and game controllers'. In your case I'm assuming it is 'High Definition Audio Driver'.

### Even Further Steps

You might be having more that one driver software. Uninstall any third party audio or sound drivers. This is usually a rare case. Do not uninstall the audio driver that comes with your processor (in your case 'Intel Audio'). Then restart your P.C and follow the steps at the beginning to set as default playback. It should work this time. Do not do the update for the drivers this time around. This will cause the drivers to get re-installed.

Comment: Still not working, it didn't show up, but I can affirm that it's detected.

Comment: @Patrick I have improved my answer with further steps. Please check above.

Comment: the device manager stated that all devices are up to date. And still no sound.

Comment: Maybe there is a clash between your realtek and High Definition drivers. Can i get a screenshot of your device manager's 'Sound,video and game controllers' section ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/kdCsA43.png

Comment: @Patrick i hav e improved the answer once again. Please check above.

Comment: I uninstalled the third party drivers, now it says that "no audio devices are installed". It seems that the Windows is ignoring the Intel Audio driver.

Comment: Is your windows 32 or 64 bit ?

Comment: My Windows is 64 bits.

Comment: @Patrick  need more information to help you. What is your pc make and model ? Did intel audio come pre-installed ? Also please confirm if audio is working for linux at the moment ? Is it a dual boot ? Is it a laptop or desktop ?

Comment: I did a clear Windows 7 install yesterday. It's a LG laptop, model C400. I guess the Windows installed the Intel Audio driver, but I'm not sure.

Comment: if you are familiar with irc chat ..i can help you live at [IRC](https://webchat.freenode.net/) Much Faster . I will be on the channel #superuser

Comment: I think I found the solution (odd, by the way) in this answer: http://superuser.com/a/891503/342010. A full shutdown worked like a charm.